# Using row values from one table to determine fields to select from another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have multiple tables in a MySQL database, and I would like to be able to use row values from one table as the columns to select from another table. For instance, suppose that my tables `description` and `information` were as follows:

```
 -------------
| description |
 -------------
id  colalias    privacy
--  --------    -------
1   fname       3
2   lname       3
3   salary      2
4   empid       1

 -------------
| information |
 -------------
id  fname   lname   salary  empid
--  -----   -----   ------  -----
1   Bob     White   50000   12345
2   Tom     Black   75000   54321
3   Sue     Green   82000   67890
4   Ann     Brown   63000   09876
```

Suppose that I want to return a table that pulls all data from `information` where the `description.privacy` is equal to 3. So I'd like to have an output of

```
fname   lname   
-----   -----   
Bob     White   
Tom     Black   
Sue     Green   
Ann     Brown
```

since only the `fname` and `lname` fields have that privacy level. I'm not an expert in writing SQL queries, and I have no control over the existing database design. If this is an obvious thing to do, I apologize for being ignorant of it, but I would truly appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE - NEW ANSWER**

After @Brian commenting I have realized that per my comment below, a mySQL `subquery` is likely going to do the trick allowing you to query based on a previous result.

There is a fairly good overview on them at [RoseIndia.net](http://www.roseindia.net/mysql/mysql5/writing-subqueries.shtml) that will give you a good start.

**OLD ANSWER**

You're most likely looking for a `LEFT JOIN` to achieve this.

I'm assuming that the `id` columns are related to each other to start with. Personally I would have 2 separate primary keys and then relate 1 table to the other using a foreign key but moving on.

I would suggest you check out [KeithJBrown.co.uk](http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/mysql/mysql_p5.php) that has a good explanation and some good examples of different types of joins.

Finally, to only get the columns you want, you simply specify them as `SELECT information.fname, information.lname` in the SQL statement.

I hope this helps you get on the right track, also, next time do a bit of research with Google first, try a few things then when you get stuck ask for help.

Comment: I think OP is wanting to determine, dynamically, the fields lname and fname, based on their privacy rating of 3, rather than simply joining to pull out those fields

Comment: Brian speaks truly. It has to be dynamic. The tables I listed are not my actual tables. I simplified for clarity, but if I can see how to do it for my example, then I'll be able to do it on the real tables.

Comment: I see what you mean in re-looking at that data structure, @agarrett, also Google "mysql subquery", I will amend my answer for you now

Answer (score 0):

You are actually really hampered here by your data model, the link between privacy level and data should be best modelled in tables by data alone, not by linking *data* (privacy level) to *structure* (field names).

Do you have any scope *at all* to change the data model, even if only adding in new stuff (i.e. not changing/removing existing model)?

What you're trying isn't impossible, but it's much harder work...

Edit - quick example of using dynamic SQL:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,27979,30437

Edit - example of a data model that would help, albeit it is a big refactor to what you're perhaps working with, so the dynamic SQL route might be more practical...

```
field_name  field_security_level  user_id  user_emp_id  field_value
----------  --------------------  -------  -----------  -----------
fname       3                     1        12345        Bob
lname       3                     1        12345        White
```

Comment: I have pretty much no control over the structure of the tables. If I *did* have some control to add my own tables, what would make this problem easier?

Comment: Edited with some further info, I think the data model refactor might be larger than is worth your while, and has its own impact, so looking into dynamic SQL might be your best bet